# How to use rsyslog templates to write log files based on a wildcard syslog facility?

Tags: centos7, systemd, rsyslog

My systemd target/service design has multiple sub-services all uniquely identified. My  `test.target` requires 10 `test-@.service` instances. The result is target runs and there are 10 identified services. e.g. `test-@0.service, test-@1.service, etc...` This is a common way to have a target control a bunch of similar services.

Each service has the Systemd SyslogIndentifer set to `SyslogIdentifier=test-%i`. So when it logs to syslog/journald, the facility name is `test-0,test-1, etc...`

Here's a sample journald log, note the facility `test-0`:

```
Oct 29 03:32:35 black-node.local test-0[5015]: 1603942355636701,CON,192.168.10.151:57458,4,12,1,-,-,-,timeout expired; UDP connection assumed closed.
```

Now, I need/want to log all of the resulting `test-*` syslog messaging into a separate log file. I tried adding the following in `/etc/rsyslog.d/test.conf:

```
$template TestFile,"/var/log/test-%syslogfacility-text%.log"
test-*.*   ?TestFile
```

But I receive the following errors when restoring rsyslogd (`sudo systemctl restart rsyslog`):

```
Message from syslogd@black-node at Oct 29 03:19:22 ...
 rsyslogd:file './.* ? TestFile': open error: Permission denied [v8.24.0-52.el7 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2433 ]

Message from syslogd@black-node at Oct 29 03:19:22 ...
 rsyslogd:action 'action 2' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8.24.0-52.el7 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
```

It's not file permissions, and the rsyslog error 2359 page says it could be selinux (!!!) related. So I tried turning off selinux (`sudo setenforce 0`) and restarting rsyslogd again:

```
Message from syslogd@black-node at Oct 29 03:18:07 ...
 systemd:Started System Logging Service.

Message from syslogd@black-node at Oct 29 03:18:07 ...
 rsyslogd:error during parsing file /etc/rsyslog.d/test.conf, on or before line 7: warnings occured in file '/etc/rsyslog.d/transfers.conf' around line 7 [v8.24.0-52.el7 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2207 ]

Message from syslogd@black-node at Oct 29 03:18:07 ...
 rsyslogd:action '*' treated as ':omusrmsg:*' - please use ':omusrmsg:*' syntax instead, '*' will not be supported in the future [v8.24.0-52.el7 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2184 ]
```

That's a little more encouraging? I have no clue how or if I should apply :omusrmsg: but I tried:

```
$template TestFile,"/var/log/test-%syslogfacility-text%.log"
test-:omusrmsg:*.*   ?TestFile
```

Now rsyslog restarts fine, no errors or complaints, but also no new log file.

At this point I'm going crazy, so I isolate the 1st service facility `test-0`:

```
$template TestFile,"/var/log/test-%syslogfacility-text%.log"
test-0.*   ?TestFile
```

I see the logs in messages/journald, but my log file isn't created and there aren't any rsyslog errors when restarting it.

How can I simply aggregate multiple log facilities into one log file? I can't even seem to get the general dynamic log file type case to work?! Any tips would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SyslogIdentifier=` and `test-0` are not a facility but a program name. Replace `%syslogfacility-text%` by `%programname%` and use a legacy property filter [selector](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/filters.html) like

```
:programname, startswith, "test-"  ?TestFile
```

Comment: You're a life saver!